# Tree implementation in C++: Cannot convert Node to int* Ask Question

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

**I'm currently working on my homework. Below is the program for construction of binary tree which I wrote. I'm getting the error that, "cannot convert 'node**' to 'int*' in assignment". Can you please help me out here?**

````
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

struct node
{
    char data;
    int *left,*right;
};

int main()
{
    node *T; //ROOT of tree
    node *p,*q; //address of first node in T
    T=new node;
    T->left=NULL;
    T->right=NULL;
    T->data='A';


    p=new node;
    p->left=NULL;
    p->right=NULL;
    p->data='B';
    T->left=&p;

    p=new node;
    p->left=NULL;
    p->right=NULL;
    p->data='C';
    T->right=&p;

    q=new node;
    q->left=NULL;
    q->right=NULL;
    q->data='D';
    p->left=&q;

    return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 3):

Change your structure definition to

```
struct node
{
    char data;
    node *left,*right;  // <- node * here
};
```

Tree node has a recursive definition.

Answer (score 1):

Change your structure as @TarekD suggested, the problem is you are trying to cast a node* into an int*

```
T->left=&p;

T->right=&p;

p->left=&q;
```